# What is the modern way to rename a volume on Mac OS X?

Tags: c, macos, filesystems

I'm trying to write some code to change the volume name on Mac OS X.  Unfortunately, the documentation in this area is less than helpful.

What I have found so far:

- `FSGetVolumeInfo` can be used to *get* the volume name, but the corresponding `FSSetVolumeInfo` lacks the parameters to set it.
- `PBGetVolumeInfoSync` can be used to *get* the volume name, but reading the docs for the corresponding `PBSetVolumeInfoSync`, it does not appear to be possible to set it.  In practice when I try to do so, I get error code -35.
- `PBHRenameSync` can be used to "rename a file, directory, or volume."  However, it is marked as deprecated and "replaced by `PBRenameUnicodeSync`." Naturally, `PBRenameUnicodeSync` is documented as "renames a file or folder", which hardly makes it a viable replacement.

So what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that the name of the volume would be the same as the name of the root directory of that volume, so that something like `FSRenameUnicode` should work.